# AngularJS and ui-bootstrap injection error(?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

Forgive me if this error is somewhat simple, but i seem to be getting these injection error and the debugger in firefox doesn't seem to help me.
Here the code snippets

This is the Controller file in question

```
App.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope,$uibModal, menuAppetizers) {
$scope.menuAppetizers; });

App.controller('AppetizerMenuController',
     ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', 'ParseService', '$location', '$q', '$uibModal',
     function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, ParseService, $q, $uibModal) {
       //.... needless code not related to the problem

       $scope.open = function (_menuAppetizer) {
         console.log("We get into the modal open");
         var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
             controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
             templateUrl: "Views/menu/myModal.html",
             resolve: function () {
                 return _menuAppetizer;
             }
         });
     }
 }]);
```

in the app.js file where i call for ui-bootstrap:

```
var App = angular.module('App',
 ['ngRoute', "ui.bootstrap"])
```

Which seem to look fine to me. This consist most of the routing for my project.

The view for the AppetizersController which only show the modal snippet:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="open(menuAppetizers)"
   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal.html">Nutrition Info</button>
```

Which should go to the modal.html and open that content which is listed here

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal.html" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Nutrition Info</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Calories: {{menuAppetizers.NutritionInfo}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry if i didn't post enough code, I can get the modal to work, but when i try to use $modal.open it return a injector error. Did i make a mistake injecting? I looked up this problem and i seem to be following the rules i got from the documentation from ui-bootstrap. Am I missing something? I'm pretty new to angularjs/ui-bootstrap.

Error I get:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=menuAppetizersProvider%20%3C-%20menuAppetizers%20%3C-%20ModalInstanceCtrl

 e/<() angular.min.js:107
 Ze/this.$get</<() angular.min.js:80
 f/<() angular.min.js:119
 lf/this.$get</n.prototype.$eval() angular.min.js:133
lf/this.$get</n.prototype.$digest() angular.min.js:130
lf/this.$get</n.prototype.$apply() angular.min.js:133
 h() angular.min.js:87
 K() angular.min.js:91
 Sf/</z.onload()
```

Comment: can you tell me that where have added ui-bootstrap js. I think there was sequence break

Comment: It added into the index file where all the other scripts should be. from the debugger in firefox, the error seem to be located into ModalInstanceCtrl. If I'm reading it right. Just no clue how to resolve it.

Comment: can you attach the error stack trace at the bottom of your question? "ModalInstanceCtrl" seems not needing any `$uibModal` injection because there is no logic inside and there is no scope isolation. Is `AppetizerMenuController ` the parent scope?

Comment: Alright I added in the error stack and the error i see. and yes, the ModalInstanceCtrl is the child of a AppetizerMenuController

Comment: Do you have menuAppetizers service/factory/provider?
Cause that seems to be missing

Comment: No, It wasn't intended to be a service/factory. Rather it was intended to take parent menuAppetizer into the scope of the modal. When removing supposed menuAppetizers in the controller i don't seem to have the error anymore. but the modal itself won't show up now. It was just showing. Curse. AngularJS is up and down with me. Modal ruining this for me dangit..

Comment: Now I get your problem. Can you try my posted answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the injection:

```
App.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', 'menuAppetizers',function ($scope,$uibModal, menuAppetizers) {
$scope.menuAppetizers; }]);

App.controller('AppetizerMenuController',
     ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$location', 'ParseService', '$q', '$uibModal',
     function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, ParseService, $q, $uibModal) {
.... needless code not related to the problem
```

`'ParseService', '$location', '` where inverted.

Comment: $location, ParseService are placed mis but $uibModal is still right now

Answer (score 1):

Your resolve should be:

```
resolve: {
    menuAppetizers: function () {
        return _menuAppetizer;
    }
}
```

In your controller, you declared a menuAppetizers dependency, but in your resolve, you did not declare a menuAppetizers object instead you declared a function, that's why it is not working.

Comment: Why does that work?  Well it working as in it reach that part now via console.log. I think I broke the modal content part myself. So I should be able to fix that part after thinking about it. Many Thank.

Comment: In your controller, you declared a menuAppetizers dependency, but in your resolve, you did not declare a menuAppetizers object instead you declared a function, that's why it is not working.